# FireAlpaca Won't save to C Drive

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, wine, windows-10, acer

I used Wine to install FireAlpaca, which is a free form of photoshop, and everything works, however, when I go to save it says it can't even though I specifically tell it to save to the windows partition. I can access the windows partition and see the different files, but I can't appear to write to them, is there a solution? Also, in the event I need it, how does one go about uninstalling software installed with wine?

Comment: Are you talking about a real NTFS partition or wine's simulated c: drive?

Comment: You'll be impressed with the features if you check out [Krita](https://userbase.kde.org/Krita/Manual) from the default Ubuntu repositories.